# Accessing DropDownList inside GridView in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have following code in my GridView in Webform in ASP.net

```
<columns>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="DESIGNATION">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                             <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">Designation<br /></asp:Literal>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesignation" runat="server" BorderColor="#0000CC"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESIGNATION") %>'></asp:Literal>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>

<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="CNIC">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                         <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">CNIC<br /></asp:Literal>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchBox" BorderColor="#0000CC"></asp:TextBox>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CNIC") %>'></asp:Literal>
                     </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to access DropDownList in my code behind file in C#.
I have Tried in many ways using find control method but did not work.Please guide me.

Comment: You want to find dropdown on button click or what?

Comment: `DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gv1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlDesignation");` Try this..

Comment: Drop down list will be used as a filter in GridView.Please also tell me is there built in filters in Gridview since I did not find any?

Comment: please refer this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Excel-like-AutoFilter-Feature-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx

Comment: Error->Multiple controls with the same ID 'Literal1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: It means that you have more than one control on page with ID 'Literal1'

Comment: Why error? since I was not accessing Literal1.

Comment: Please use unique names for a whole row. FindControl won't work if ids are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gridview RowDataBound Try some thing like this:

```
protected void Grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDesignation");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The DropDownList exists inside all rows in the GridView. You need to find the specific row if you wish to do that.

If you know the row index, they try this:

```
DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)gview.Row(index).FindControl("ddlDesignation");
```

Or you can also find all rows in the Row Databound event of the GridView.

```
DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDesignation");
```

Comment: I got error->Multiple controls with the same ID 'Literal1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Please use unique names for a whole row. FindControl won't work if ids are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

In your RowDataBound of GridView:

```
  protected void gdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gdv.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)gdv.HeaderRow.FindControl("txt");
            }
        }
```